# move Astr EVM from Metamask to Polkadt.js

Tags: polkadot-js, evm

I have Astar(Astr) on as an EVM on Metamask and want to eventually take profit on some of it and move that portion to USDT.  My plan is to swap it for DOT first on Polkadot.js wallet.  The problem is that the the Polkadot wallet does not start with 0x, therefore Metamask can only send to 0x...   I've done all of the research on  Astar.doc.network plus youtube videos, I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To swap ASTR for DOT, I think you can use hydradx or stellaswap:

https://app.hydradx.io/trade/swap

https://app.stellaswap.com/exchange/swap